# Removing all <br> in a token in Gatling/Scala

Tags: scala, gatling

I have a http response and I save a token using regex and check.

However the token contains a lot of html br (breaks) 's and I want to strip them and merge the token to be one string.

I found this replace function for removing br's:

```
val str = "{$token}"
    str.replace("<br/>", "")
```

But how do I implement that in Gatling script? as .exec? or could I just say:

```
val str = "{$token}"
    str.replace("<br/>", "")
```

and then:

```
.exec(http("request_1")
    .post("/SS/?a=internett")
    .header("header_name", "${str}")
    .body(ElFileBody("request.xml"))
    .basicAuth("${y}","y"))
```

Comment: relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/86485

Comment: information overload! I have updated the question and it should (?) be a short answer (?)

Comment: also tried: .exec(session=>{
    val str = ("$token").replaceAll("<br/>", "")
    session})

Comment: no one that can help, please?